# Windows 10 no internet access with 4G dongle & LAN

Tags: routing, netsh, windows-10-v20h2

I have the following setup on a remote computer:

- Ethernet connection: only for local network - no internet access
- 4G dongle: internet access

When combining the two, I don't have internet access.
Upon investigating the route table I've found this persistent route:

```
Network Address  Netmask  Gateway Metric

0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0  10.128.x.1 Default
```

(note: the 10.128.x.1 is the gateway for the LAN connection)

So basically it uses the LAN for internet traffic.

I've used the following commands to alter the routing table:

```
route -p add 10.128.x.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.128.x.1 metric 330 if 21 
route -p delete 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 10.128.x.1 if 21
```

(note: if 21 is the Ethernet adapter)

But this didn't had any effect. The Windows pc still doesn't have internet connection when using both 4G dongle + LAN. I cannot add persistent route for 4G dongle as this IP address changes every time it connects. Also, as I don't have physical access to the pc I cannot do much testing when both connections are active as teamviewer also drops.

Next to this, I've also did the following:

- `netsh winsock reset`
- `netsh int ip reset`
- Changed metric of the 4G dongle in 'Advanced TCP/IP settings' to 1

All of this did not have any effect. I've just tested the same setup on another PC and this one does chooses the 4G dongle correctly for internet access.

So what could be possibly wrong with this remote pc routing? Or could it be some other cause?

Comment: Does your LAN connection really need that default gateway if it's not connected to the internet? Does the subnet perhaps conflict with the 4G connection's subnet?

Comment: The default gateway may not be necessary indeed - the PC only needs to connect to PLM interfaces in the same subnet. My purpose was to force the LAN connection to use only for this 10.128.x.x subnet. Normally no conflict with the 4G subnet (this also changes every time you re-connect). Thx